# If edit text contains spaces then show error

Tags: android

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);     

if(condition)
{

}
```

if edittext containing space bar then show error

Comment: i want the condition and  code

Comment: Have you tried writing any code for this? or just looking for ready code for use !!!!

Comment: can you please elaborate what is the condition and error?

Comment: You can simply not allow the space to be used...

Comment: thx for giving the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no " " space in the EditText is what you want.
Nobody will provide you with a ready working code. Here are some pointers to proceed.

```
String a = text.getText().toString();");
```

This will help you get the string in the edittext

So you have the string that the user had entered in the edittexxt.
No you need to use a simple function that will check if a character is present in the string.

```
String s= String from edittext;
boolean p=s.contains(" ");
if(p)
    //call function for error
else
    //safe to proceed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to show error.

```
  EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
  if(text .getText().toString().contains(" "))
  {
     text.setError("Field cannot be have space.");                     
  }
```

Comment: And what about `NULL` ?

Comment: you can check text .getText().length() > 0 for null

Comment: Or TextUtils.isEmpty(text.getText().toString())

Comment: thx for  giving the code.